# cannot see option to turn off my google news feed

Tags: chrome-for-android

I am using a Moto G7 Power ,  android phone

When I open the Google browser (chrome I suppose), it says on the bottom
"discover, updates, search, more...".   If I choose "more..." and then 'settings', then it says

[image]

I see no news option to turn off

Answer (score 0):

After clicking "more..." on the bottom, and getting that settings page up, as you did..

choose 'general' then see it says 
'discover  - you'll see stories related to your interests..'

turn that 'discover' off.

That closes the news feed.